# Why does my attempt at pivot filtering throw me an "object does not support this property or method" error?

Tags: excel, vba

```vba
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim field As PivotField

Set datasheet = Sheets(1)

Set PT = datasheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
Set field = PT.PivotFields("Chapter_Desc")

field.ClearAllFilters
field.datasheet = "Georgia"

Set field = Nothing
Set PT = Nothing
```

I expected this to filter pivot field `Chapter_Desc` to `Georgia`.

Instead it give me an error at line `field.datasheet = "Georgia`

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
    Dim f As PivotItem
    For Each f In field.PivotItems
        If f.Name = "Geogia" Then
            f.Visible = True
        Else
            f.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
```